# change background image for harmony drawing app

Tags: javascript, html

i am working on [mrdoob harmony](http://mrdoob.com/projects/harmony/) drawing web application and i want to add a button in the menu to add an image to the background.i have found this example of background image insertion http://jsfiddle.net/tc3r4sj5/ but how can i make a button for it in the menu?

this is the code of the menu from harmony where i need to create a new button

```js
function Menu()
{
    this.init();
}

Menu.prototype =
{
    container: null,

    foregroundColor: null,
    backgroundColor: null,

    selector: null,
    //save: null,
    exportImage: null,
    resetBrush: null,
    clear: null,
    //about: null,

    init: function()
    {
        function newColorWell(width, height, identifier)
        {
            var well = document.createElement("canvas");
            well.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            well.width = width;
            well.height = height;
            well.className = 'well ' + identifier;
            return well;
        }

        var option, space, separator, color_width = 20, color_height = 15;

        this.container = document.createElement("div");
        this.container.className = 'gui menu';
        this.container.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.container.style.top = '-7px';

        this.foregroundColor = newColorWell(color_width, color_height, 'fg-color');
        this.container.appendChild(this.foregroundColor);

        this.setForegroundColor( COLOR );



        this.backgroundColor = newColorWell(color_width, color_height, 'bg-color');
        this.container.appendChild(this.backgroundColor);

        this.setBackgroundColor( BACKGROUND_COLOR );



        this.selector = document.createElement("select");
        this.selector.style.marginRight = '3px';

        for (i = 0; i < BRUSHES.length; i++)
        {
            option = document.createElement("option");
            option.id = i;
            option.textContent = BRUSHES[i].toUpperCase();
            this.selector.appendChild(option);
        }

        this.container.appendChild(this.selector);



        this.save = document.createElement("span");
       this.save.style.marginRight = '3px';
        this.container.appendChild(this.save);

      

        this.exportImage = document.createElement("span");

        this.exportImage.style.marginLeft = '3px';
        this.exportImage.style.marginRight = '3px';
        this.container.appendChild(this.exportImage);

        this.resetBrush = document.createElement("span");
   
        this.resetBrush.style.marginRight = '3px';
        this.container.appendChild(this.resetBrush);

        this.clear = document.createElement("Clear");
        this.clear.className = 'button';
        this.clear.textContent = 'CLEAR';
        this.clear.style.marginRight = '3px';
        this.container.appendChild(this.clear);
  
  
  
  

  
  
  
  

        this.about = document.createElement("About");

        this.container.appendChild(this.about);
    },

    setForegroundColor: function( color )
    {
        this.foregroundColor.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + color[0] + ', ' + color[1] +', ' + color[2] + ')';
    },

    setBackgroundColor: function( color )
    {
        this.backgroundColor.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + color[0] + ', ' + color[1] +', ' + color[2] + ')';
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no event for `clear` button..

Comment: question was edited and the code of menu.js is provided

Answer (score 1):

In your menu `init` function (`Menu.prototype.init`) you need to add couple of nodes - the `button` and the `input[type="file"]`.

You do this using this code:

```js
// add background control
this.background = document.createElement("div");
this.background.className = "button background";
this.background.innerHTML = "Background";
this.container.appendChild(this.background);
// add fileupload
this.uploader = document.createElement("input");
this.uploader.type = 'file';
this.uploader.className = "file-uploader";
this.background.appendChild(this.uploader);
```

To hide the input file and make it work you need to add this style:

```css
.background {
  position:relative;
}
.background > input {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here is a [bin](http://output.jsbin.com/wawebil) with the result.

Comment: I was not able to make it change the background after adding the js code from http://jsfiddle.net/tc3r4sj5/ to the main.js of harmony.if you can help ... many thanks

Comment: Is this answer your question?